# ひとつの検索条件に対して、複数のSELECTを実行するには、どんなクエリを作成するのがいいでしょうか？

Tags: mysql, sql, database, redash

データベースやSQLに関して、初心者です。おかしな質問していたらご指摘ください。

データ分析のため、サービスに登録したユーザーの情報を複数の切り口から確認したいです。

抽出対象のユーザーの情報のテーブル（`users`）とレコードは下記です。
`source`は登録元、`status`は登録状態です。

```
+----+---------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | source        | created_at          | status   |
+----+---------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 | google        | 2020-08-11 00:00:00 | 1        | 
|  2 | yahoo         | 2020-08-12 00:00:00 | 1        |
|  3 | google        | 2020-08-13 00:00:00 | 1        |
|  4 | google        | 2020-08-14 00:00:00 | 0        |
+----+---------------+---------------------+----------+
```

ここから`status`が`1`のユーザーを抽出して、その「合計数」「登録元（`source`）ごとの合計数」「各レコードの詳細」を確認するためのクエリを作成し、複数の切り口からユーザー情報を確認したいです。

下記のように、個別のクエリを作成すれば可能ですが、抽出条件が同じクエリを複数作成することになるのが、良くないと感じています。保守性を考えると、検索条件は流用するのが好ましいと思います。
ひとつの検索条件に対して、複数のSELECTを実行するには、どんなクエリを作成するのがいいでしょうか？

「合計数」

```
select count(*) from users where status = 1;
```

「登録元（`source`）ごとの合計数」

```
select count(*), source from users where status = 1 group by source;
```

「各レコードの詳細」

```
select * from users where status = 1;
```

環境は下記です。
DB: MySQL
データ分析ツール: Redash

Comment: 「抽出条件が同じクエリを複数作成することになる」のが良くないと感じるのは何故でしょうか？　どのような問題が生じると考えていらっしゃるのでしょうか？　漠然とした質問よりも、具体的な質問をするほうが適切な回答を得られやすいと思います。

Comment: 良くないと感じる理由は、保守性が悪くなるからです。質問では、抽出条件を`status`が`1`と現実よりも簡潔なものにしています。ちなみに、これは質問に記載すべきだったのですが、「登録中」を意味しています。ただ、現実では「登録中」のユーザーの抽出条件はもっと複雑です。また、システムの改修などによって抽出条件も変わることがあります。なので、同じ抽出条件を記載することを避けたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

共通の条件でビューを作ればよいと思います。

```
create view users_status_1 as select * from users where status = 1;
```

共通でない条件を追加指定して、そのビューに対してQUERYを発行すれば実表と同じ結果が得られます。

```
select count(*) from users_status_1;
select count(*), source from users_status_1 group by source;
select * from users_status_1;
```